# Product List Position Attribution in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have added the data layer on my website and everything is working fine but when I see the product list position table, the attribution is not working.
[image]

The table is showing the position and list view and click data but add to cart, checkout and purchase is not attributed with this data.
I have crosschecked the data layer with Google documentation and it is looking good. I don't know what's the issue.
The data layer Code

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: show details and other dataLayer situation, pls

Comment: @MichelePisani please check

Comment: Check in the reports if this behavior is also present with the data of the previous 48h.

Comment: @MichelePisani it's the same behavior in the last 48 hours data.